# jQuery: Animation set to start on pageload; IE waits length of animation before beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I've got a jQuery animation that I want to start when the page loads. Here's my code:

```
function repeatscroll() {
    if ($('div#photoscroll img').css('margin-left') == '0px') {
        var margin = '-770px';
    } else {
        var margin = '0px';
    }
    $('div#photoscroll img').animate({'margin-left': margin}, 20000, 'linear', function() {repeatscroll();});
}

$(document).ready(function() {alert('in');repeatscroll();});
```

This takes a long strip of photos and 'scrolls' it to the right, then back to the left.
As you can see, it is called on `$(document).ready()`.

This works fine with browsers that aren't IE. But, with IE, there's a problem.

When the page loads in IE, the `alert('in')` is called. But, `repeatscroll()` isn't called until 20000 ms later, exactly the time the animation is set to take. I know that `repeatscroll()` isn't getting called because I've tried putting an `alert` line at the top of it, which isn't called until after the delay.

## [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XJu3W/)

**So, why does IE wait to start the animation, and how can I fix this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *IE8 and lower* this:

```
$('div#photoscroll img').css('margin-left')
```

[returns `auto`](http://jsfiddle.net/XJu3W/3/) the first time, whereas in other browsers (including IE9), it returns `0px` as expected.

One way to fix it is to add this CSS:

```
#photoscroll img {
    margin: 0
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/XJu3W/1/